# add text in my css and display it in the html page email

Tags: css, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I was wondering if there is a way to add "text" in the css so the html page can write it out.
This is because the html page wont be able to handle my inparameters (${var}).
I am using jenkins editable email plugin

So I have my css:

```
<style type="text/css">
a{color:#4a72af}
body{background-color:#e4e4e4}
body,p{margin:0;padding:0}
img{display:block}
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{margin:0 0 .8em 0}
h3{font-size:28px;color:#444!important;font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif}
h4{font-size:22px;color:#4a72af!important;font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif}
h5{font-size:18px;color:#444!important;font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif}
p{font-size:12px;color:#444!important;font-family:"Lucida Grande","Lucida Sans","Lucida Sans    Unicode",sans-serif;line-height:1.5}
ol li img{display:inline;height:20px}
/*div styles*/
.news{text-align:center;padding-top:15px;}
.content{width:720px;margin:0 auto;background-color:white}
.round_border{margin-bottom:5px;-webkit-border-radius:6px;-moz-border-radius:6px;border- radius:6px;margin-top:0;font-size:14px;padding:6px;border:1px solid #ccc}
.status{background-color:<%= 
        ${MyVar} == "Open" ? 'green' : 'red' %>;font-size:28px;font-weight:bold;color:white;width:720px;height:52px;margin-bottom:18px;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;border-collapse:collapse;background-repeat:no-repeat}
.status .info{color:white!important;text-shadow:0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3);font-size:32px;line-height:36px;padding:8px 0}
.main img{width:38px;margin-right:16px;height:38px}
.main table{font-size:14px;}
.main table th{text-align:right;}
.bottom-message{width:720px;cellpadding:5px;cellspacing:0px}
.bottom-message .message{font-size:13px;color:#aaa;line-height:18px;text-align:center}
.bottom-message .designed{font-size:13px;color:#aaa;line-height:18px;font-style: italic;text-align:right}
</style>
<body>
<div class="content round_border">
<div class="status">
<p class="info">TEST</p>
</div>
<!-- status -->
<div class="main round_border">
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
 <th>Name:</th>
 <td>HERE IS WHERE THE TEXT SHOULD BE</td>
 </tr>
 ....
```

As you can see in my text I got a ${MyVar} in the css. That works just fine. But now I want another ${MyVar2} that will have a string that I would like to go to here:

```
<td>HERE IS WHERE THE TEXT SHOULD BE</td>
```

because I cant write

```
<td>${MyVar2}</td>
```

that will generate error

so I would like to use it something like

```
.test ${MyVar2}
```

and then add this to

```
<td class="test"></td>
```

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to monkey patch something instead of figuring out where the actual error is coming from.

Comment: let me ask myself.. will I read that code?? mmm nah!

Comment: Well I know the problem. I need to write a plugin to get around this since this is a wrapped code. Thats why I want to get around it with this quick fix if it is possible

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could use the ::before or ::after pseudo-elements and set their content:

```
div::after
{
    content: 'Hello!';
}
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wj28C/)

Comment: It didnt work. :-( Might have to do that this is send in an email and is not shown in a browser.

Comment: Try using just one colon: div:after

Comment: I tryied that as well. It works well in http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_sel_after but not when I run it with the mail.